# "had non-zero exit status" error, how to solve it?

Tags: r, macos, github

I am trying to load a package in RStudio from GitHub but I get an error. I have also updated all the packages in order to see if this was the problem but I still get the same error. I have a MAC pc (I don't know if this may cause some problems).
I have tried many things, like downloading the package... but it still doesn't work. But I really need it to work.

The link of the package that I would like to load is: https://github.com/andrewraim/COMMultReg

and there is written that in order to load it I need to run

```
install.packages("roxygen2")
library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)
install_github("andrewraim/COMMultReg")
```

and this is what I get:

```
Downloading GitHub repo andrewraim/COMMultReg@HEAD
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/n0/4lmr1lrj7qqfylmh6s8qx0nr0000gn/T/RtmpSQ4zEZ/remotesa4070bcf835/andrewraim-COMMultReg-5a927d9/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘COMMultReg’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘COMMultReg_0.1.0.tar.gz’
   
* installing *source* package ‘COMMultReg’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c MultIterator.cpp -o MultIterator.o
In file included from MultIterator.cpp:1:
In file included from ./MultIterator.h:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c cmb.cpp -o cmb.o
In file included from cmb.cpp:1:
In file included from ./cmb.h:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c cmm-reg.cpp -o cmm-reg.o
In file included from cmm-reg.cpp:2:
In file included from ./cmm-reg.h:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c cmm.cpp -o cmm.o
In file included from cmm.cpp:1:
In file included from ./cmm.h:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c util.cpp -o util.o
In file included from util.cpp:1:
In file included from ./util.h:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:57:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/DataFrame.h:136:18: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
            SEXP data = Parent::get__();
                 ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o COMMultReg.so MultIterator.o cmb.o cmm-reg.o cmm.o util.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.14) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.14) than being linked (10.13)
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-COMMultReg/00new/COMMultReg/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘COMMultReg’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: d_cmb, d_cmb_sample, d_cmm, d_cmm_sample, gunterize, loglik_score_fim_cmm, normconst_cmb, normconst_cmm, r_cmb
Errore: loading failed
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/COMMultReg’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/n0/4lmr1lrj7qqfylmh6s8qx0nr0000gn/T//RtmpSQ4zEZ/filea404d43fac4/COMMultReg_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can somebody help??
Thanks

Comment: The error says *undefined exports*.
So it sounds like there was a problem in the NAMESPACE file.
In the meantime, the package has been updated.
Does the updated version load correctly?